# SQL 2005 Random Letters only in same format (obfuscation)

Tags: sql, random, replace, nested, obfuscation

I am looking for a way to generate random letters to replace existing letters in a selected fields, namely the 'FullName' field.
I need to keep all data in the same format, so letters remain letters, numbers remain numbers, special characters remain special characters, spaces remain spaces.

so 'John-Paul Jones' should become 'SLFD-ANED PQZDT'.

I have tried to do this (focusing on letters only first) using the REPLACE function but after about 10 nested REPLACEs it stops working correctly.

Not looking for alternative ways to obfuscate, just looking for a way to be able to do the above mentioned.

In an ideal world i would love to have this as a function that I could just call upon within my scripts, not sure how to do anything that advanced though, if anyone does know both how to resolve the below and also how to create a function with it, that would be perfect.

here is my SQL if anyone can help;

```
USE [DATABASE1]

DECLARE @A AS CHAR;
DECLARE @B AS CHAR;
DECLARE @C AS CHAR;
DECLARE @D AS CHAR;
DECLARE @E AS CHAR;
DECLARE @F AS CHAR;
DECLARE @G AS CHAR;
DECLARE @H AS CHAR;
DECLARE @I AS CHAR;
DECLARE @J AS CHAR;
DECLARE @K AS CHAR;
DECLARE @L AS CHAR;
DECLARE @M AS CHAR;
DECLARE @N AS CHAR;
DECLARE @O AS CHAR;
DECLARE @P AS CHAR;
DECLARE @Q AS CHAR;
DECLARE @R AS CHAR;
DECLARE @S AS CHAR;
DECLARE @T AS CHAR;
DECLARE @U AS CHAR;
DECLARE @V AS CHAR;
DECLARE @W AS CHAR;
DECLARE @X AS CHAR;
DECLARE @Y AS CHAR;
DECLARE @Z AS CHAR;

SET @A = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @B = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @C = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @D = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @E = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @F = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @G = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @H = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @I = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @J = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @K = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @L = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @M = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @N = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @O = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @P = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @Q = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @R = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @S = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @T = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @U = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @V = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @W = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @X = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @Y = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));
SET @Z = CHAR(CAST((90 - 65) * RAND() + 65 AS INT));

SELECT @A AS A
    ,@B AS B
    ,@C AS C
    ,@D AS D
    ,@E AS E
    ,@F AS F
    ,@G AS G
    ,@H AS H
    ,@I AS I
    ,@J AS J
    ,@K AS K
    ,@L AS L
    ,@M AS M
    ,@N AS N
    ,@O AS O
    ,@P AS P
    ,@Q AS Q
    ,@R AS R
    ,@S AS S
    ,@T AS T
    ,@U AS U
    ,@V AS V
    ,@W AS W
    ,@X AS X
    ,@Y AS Y
    ,@Z AS Z

SELECT c.ClientFullName
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(c.ClientFullName, 'A', @A), 'B', @B), 'C', @C), 'D', @D), 'E', @E), 'F', @F), 'G', @G), 'H', @H), 'I', @I), 'J', @J), 'K', @K), 'L', @L), 'M', @M), 'N', @N), 'O', @O), 'P', @P), 'Q', @Q), 'R', @R), 'S', @S), 'T', @T), 'U', @U), 'V', @V), 'W', @W), 'X', @X), 'Y', @Y), 'Z', @Z)
FROM [DATABASE1].[dbo].[CLIENTS] c
```

thank you in advance to anyone who took the time to read this

Comment: "all spaces and special characters should remain the same at all times for testing invalid inputs." Wut? Input testing should happen before storing data in a database! And, will you need to de-scramble your data at a later time? And, what silly law is this? because it all seem deterministic, and easy to crack. I don't see this as a way to secure PII. False sense of security is a dangerous thing. A half-better way of doing this is by simply replacing each letter to a single given character e.g. Replace "John-Paul Jones" with "AAAA-BBBB CCCCC", no clear way to revert,

Comment: I have to agree, keeping the length of the original string, the non-alphanumeric symbols, and alphanumeric type leaks too much of the original data to be considered obfuscated and anonymized.

Comment: thanks for replies. We are looking to take a backup of our client's db who are based in a foreign country whose laws dictated that no sensitive data can leave their country. As a result we need to have the data as closely linked as possible to the original data (i.e. we cannot test the input of the data as they do it on site). We therefore are legally allowed to keep it in the correct format so long as no data can be related back to a person.

Comment: So having 'FGLE-GLOA QPZCB' would mean that we can't link it back but at the same time if they are having issues we need to be able to see if they have entered something that might be causing an issue, so a # symbol or too many characters etc. replacing with a simple AAAA-BBBB CCCCC won't allow us to see if the tables are linking correctly as every name would be roughly the same. the names, although scrambled, should be distinguishable between tables. hope that clarifies a little

Comment: If you can relate it back then sensitive data is leaving the country.

Comment: Hi All, thanks again for replies so far but I have edited the question to focus on what it is I require, thanks again.

Comment: thanks Hogan but as mentioned above having a name in that format isn't sufficient to relate it back. We are keeping the format to facilitate us in supporting the client. No sensitive data will be leaving the country.

Comment: Do you realize the method you are trying to use doesn't obfuscate the data all that much. You are merely implementing a polyalphabetic substitution. This is an encryption that a human with pen and paper can break. And a computer can break in a few seconds.

Comment: Like @rabbit said. This is a very naive approach! You are not fooling anyone that wants to steal this data, only yourself. IF the data must not leave the country, are you trying to violate the law and only fool the authorities? Otherwise, simply... DON'T export it! Even if you user strong encryption, it means; "yea... we exported the data overseas, in a secure manner mind you... but it sure left the country! LOL". You guys are making a mistake. I strongly advice you to hire a security consultant to educate your managers in this manner. I dont know what else to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

> Obfuscate/scramble data in a db (sensitive data only - name, phone
>   address, account number etc.) Due to laws surrounding the transfer of
>   this data from 1 country to another it is vital that it be completely
>   random

This is called "encryption".  There are lots of resources on the internets to help you perform encryption on your data, use them.

Any attempt to roll your own will fail -- I can tell because you think that some scramble upper and lower case letters will work -- this with the perfect algorithm is only 5 bits of key size (floor(lg52))) which is tiny you want at least 256 these days.

Use existing encryption technologies to solve your problem.

---

Additional note on the link you gave:  This link is 6 years old.  In that time many tools for doing "real" encryption have become available.  Also that article specifically says this is only for creating test data -- the author makes no claim this would in any way protect your users if someone wanted to crack it.  Don't kid yourself,  with the exception of "masking" (which essentially removes the source data) everything there would be easily cracked if the data got out.

Comment: I did not once mention that the author made such a claim "mix up of the original data - i.e. FullName = Chris Carroll becomes Fullname = HSLO LCRAIRCR. for anyone who is okay with that level see a good article here". Also 6 years old or not, i felt it was a good article for someone to read if they were interested in scrambling data, I did not say that it was the bible of obfuscating.

Comment: I am aware of encryption, I am however, as my post says, simply looking for a way to replace a letter with another random letter, keep word lengths the same and keep spaces and special characters in place.